# Prove that a limit in two variables does not exists

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the following limit and Wolfram Alpha says that it does not exist, but I am not able to prove it.

$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}
$$

I have tried to move toward the origin on $x=0$ and I get:

$$
\lim_{y\to0} \frac{\sin(0)}{y^2}=0
$$

The same if I move toward the origin on $y=0$:

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(0)}{x^2}=0
$$

Then I tried to move on $x=y$:

$$
\lim_{y\to0} \frac{\sin(y^2)}{2y^2}=0
$$

I can't spot how to prove that there is another value of the index which is not $0$, but I am not able to get rid of the numerator.

Comment: You might want to take a closer look at the last case ($x = y$) you wrote down.

Comment: For future reference: this site supports most LaTeX commands, you just have to surround them with $\$$. Look at the help pages for more information.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Ok I got it. The last case is a special limit and it value is not 0 but 1/2. So the prove is done. Right?

Comment: Right, for a limit to exist, you must get the same 'limiting' value when approaching from any direction. You've shown that for two different directions, you get different values, so the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1.$$  So for any continuous function $g(x)$ such that $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, we would also have $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin g(x)}{g(x)} = 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your last limit is wrong. By substituting $x=y^2$,
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin y^2}{2y^2} = \frac12 \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac12 $$